# Есть ли аналог IF NOT EXISTS для создания DB?

Tags: postgresql

Мне перед созданием DB в запросе надо проверить не существует ли она уже.

Когда я создаю таблицу я пишу `create table if not exists ...` а есть ли синоним который будет работать с `create database` что бы мне перед созданием базы проверить нет ли ее уже? В PostgresSQL.

Comment: В Мускуле [есть](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/CREATE_DATABASE.html)

Comment: @DNS  а в Postgres?

Comment: Прямого нет. Альтернатива - зависит от того, какие действия следует предпринять, если 1) такая база есть; 2) такой базы нет.

Comment: @Akina в общем только отдельный запрос на ее существование..?

Comment: То есть то, какие действия следует предпринять - тайна? `только отдельный запрос на ее существование..?` - нет.

Comment: @Akina а да нет конечно))) просто если ее нет то  создать ее а если есть то ничего не делать и все.

Comment: Тогда просто создавайте, "и всё". Без всяких предварительных запросов и проверок. Если она есть - ну будет ошибка... судя по сказанному выше, её можно просто проигнорировать.

Comment: @Akina вот в том то и дело что мне надо без ошибки, это создание базы для тестирования, через jdbc драйвер. У меня после каждого теста создаётся и удаляется база и если какой то тест падает то удаления не происходит и и по скольку следующий тест хочет создать базу снова то падает ошибка и за одним не пройденным тестом валятся все идущие после него.

Comment: Тогда реализуйте это в формате процедуры и вызывайте её безусловно. А она уж пусть там всё проверяет... И вообще, с учётом описанного Вами вынос максимума логики на сервер - это правильно.

Comment: @Akina а что вы имеете в виду под "вынос максимума логики на сервер" я просто первый раз делаю тесты для работы с базой и не уверен что это правильный подход пересоздавать базу для каждого теста, это медленные очень тесты получаются, а если один раз создавать базу для всех тестов, то тесты начинают зависеть друг от друга мне кажется это еще хуже, так что я из 2 зол выбрал как мне кажется меньшее.

Comment: Всё, что можно делать на сервере, надо делать на сервере. Вот как в данном случае - проверить существование БД и создать при её отсутствии. Эту проверку и операцию может выполнить приложение, а может и серверная процедура. Во втором случае на сервер отправится один короткий запрос "выполнить createdb()", все проверки выполнятся внутри сервера, и вернётся один короткий ответ "выполнено", тогда как в первом - запрос "есть ли БД", ответ "нету", запрос "создай", ответ "готово"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36218838/3805142) решение вашей задачи на английском SO. Приведу ответ оттуда:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  _db TEXT := 'имя создаваемой БД';
  _user TEXT := 'пользователь';
  _password TEXT := 'пароль';
BEGIN
  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink; -- включение функции dblink 
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = _db) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Database already exists';
  ELSE
    PERFORM dblink_connect('host=localhost user=' || _user || ' password=' || _password || ' dbname=' || current_database());
    PERFORM dblink_exec('CREATE DATABASE ' || _db);
  END IF;
END
$do$
```